# requiredMessage não funcionando no selectOneMenu JSF

Tags: jsf, xhtml

Tenho a seguinte requiredMessage

```
    <h:selectOneMenu class="form-control" id="selectOlhos" value="#{corpoController.corpo.corOlhos}" required="true" requiredMessage="Selecione uma opção.">
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Escolha" itemValue="#{null}"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Verdes Claros" itemValue="Verdes Claros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Verdes Escuros" itemValue="Verdes Escuros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Castanhos Claros" itemValue="Castanhos Claros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Castanhos Escuros" itemValue="Castanhos Escuros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Indefinido" itemValue="Indefinido"></f:selectItem>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Quando a opção selecionada é o "Escolha" a opção realmente esta validada e não prossegue para o cadastro, porém a mensagem de validação não aparece, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
  <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Escolha" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}"></f:selectItem>
```